# How to convert number field to text in formula field?

Tags: custom-field, number

I created a number field with options, Required, Unique and External Id checked, and want to use formula to convert Employee Number to text to prevent commas from displaying in the field.  I tried to use VALUE(Employee_Number___c) or TEXT(Employee_Number__c) but system will not allow it.  Puzzled.

Comment: I created an external id number field and then a second field as a formula using TEXT(external_id__c) without an issue, what type of error are you getting.

Comment: You can't use the default formula to cause this, if you're trying to make the number field not use commas. Instead, make it a text field and a validation rule to prohibit anything outside 0-9.